# "snap install firefox" fails after 22.04 upgrade

Tags: firefox, 22.04, snap

I used dpkg to remove Firefox and thus repair my broken dpkg system.  I then ran (as root) "snap install firefox".  This ultimately failed with

```
- Run hook connect-plug-host-hunspell of snap "firefox" (run hook "connect-plug-host-hunspell": cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /home /tmp/snap.rootfs_mkoSWT//home: Permission denied)
```

snap.rootfs_mkoSWT does exist in /tmp, but it is empty.  Executing the given mount command manually wins the expected "mount point does not exist", which it certainly does not.

This looks like a problem with the snap package, so I'm not sure what I can do about it.  Any suggestions?